# Applying a WHERE clause conditionally in an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a pre-existing procedure that I need to modify, and in a very simplified manner, it's written similar to the example below.

The procedure gets passed in a @StudentID and a @SubjectID, and if the @SubjectID = 0, it executes the query without filtering on SubjectID at all, otherwise it executes the exact same query but filters on SubjectID.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProcedure
  @StudentID INT,   
  @SubjectID INT    
AS
BEGIN   
  IF(@SubjectID = 0)
  BEGIN  
    SELECT SomeColumns
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE StudentID = @StudentID
  END 
  BEGIN  
    SELECT SomeColumns
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE StudentID = @StudentID
    AND SubjectID = @SubjectID
  END 
END
```

This seems ridiculous to me; we now have to maintain two copies of the same query; one that filters on SubjectID and one that doesn't.  I don't have control over the fact that the application expects to pass SubjectID = 0 to get results for all subjects.

Given that I can't change the signature of the procedure, how can I rewrite this so it doesn't require two separate queries?

I've tried using a CASE statement in the WHERE clause, but I can't figure out how to conditionally include parts of the WHERE predicate.

The english translation of this problem is "IF @SubjectID = 0, return results with any SomeTable.SubjectID value, ELSE only return results where SomeTable.SubjectID = @SubjectID"

How can I accomplish that in a single query (and please no dynamic SQL suggestions)?

Comment: Look at this example: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:237794600346808562 (BTW is this Oracle?)

Comment: No, its SQL Server.  That was in a tag, but got edited out by someone else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though I don't see anything really wrong with having two separate queries, if you want to use only one query, then you can do the following:

```
SELECT SomeColumns
FROM SomeTable
WHERE StudentID = @StudentID
AND (SubjectID = @SubjectID OR @SubjectID = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks again! Just FYI, the problem with two separate queries is that in the real procedure the query is huge and complex, and if we have to modify something about it, we'd have to modify both versions, making it more prone to copy/paste mistakes, etc.